# Unity WCF Service Hosting

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to self host a WCF Service in a Unity test app.

There are no errors reported while opening the service but i can't access it or it's metadata (tested using the WcfTestClient provided with VS 2013).

Here's the code i used to create the service :

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HomeAutomationService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:38001/"));
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = _host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>() ??
                                new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);


_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHomeAutomationService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

_host.Faulted += HostOnFaulted;

_host.Open();
```

I'm trying to access the metadata on the local machine using the following Uri : http://localhost:38001/mex, but this is only returning me an HTTP400 error

Comment: Hi, sidewinder94 , have u found any solution, if yes then please share thought, I uses unity.wcf for dependency injection and unable to browse .svc file in browser.

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't find a way to **host** a WCF service in a Unity app. At the time, IIRC, it was **not** possible and have not tried again since then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a metadata exchange (mex) endpoint to your service:

```
<services>
   <service name="MyService.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
      <endpoint 
          address="http://localhost/MyService.svc" 
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="MyService.MyService"
          contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
      <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
   </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Isn't this what I did with the second AddServiceEndpoint ?
If not, would you know where I might find some documentation/examples on hosting a WCF service in Unity ? I Could only find how to consume them

Comment: while using unity i tried to expose metadata in browser , it shows endpoint not find , And one more thing all service method is working fine, i need metadata for client application, any suggestion would be appreciated